# ¿Como cargar mas de una vista parcial con un evento click?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Se que hay varias maneras de cargar una vista parcial con el evento de un botón, ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#view1").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxpanel").load("<%=Url.Action("View1") %>");
    });
    $("#view2").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxpanel").load("<%= Url.Action("View2") %>");
    });
});
</script>
```

La pregunta es, como cargo mas de una vista parcial en el mismo evento de un botón?

Comment: te refieres a cargar varias vistas al mismo tiempo en el mismo div?

Comment: Lo de los div es indistinto, lo que necesito es que teniendo una vista primaria, en el clic de un botón pueda cargar mas de una vista parcial, ya sea en un div o en div diferentes o en lo que sea la cosa es cargar dos vistas parciales en el clic de un botón

Comment: alguna novedad bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pregunta:

> como cargo mas de una vista parcial en el mismo evento de un botón?

Respuesta:

Con el código que ya tenes podrías hacer, por ejemplo, lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#view1").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxpanel").load("<%=Url.Action("View1") %>");
        // Ademas de View1 cargamos 2 vistas mas
        $("#ajaxpanel2").load("<%=Url.Action("View1_2") %>");
        $("#ajaxpanel3").load("<%=Url.Action("View1_3") %>");
    });
    $("#view2").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxpanel").load("<%= Url.Action("View2") %>");
        // Ademas de View2 cargamos 2 vistas mas
        $("#ajaxpanel2").load("<%=Url.Action("View2_2") %>");
        $("#ajaxpanel3").load("<%=Url.Action("View2_3") %>");
    });
});
```